# Cakephp Adding style to h($product['Product']['name']);

Tags: css, cakephp, styles, cakephp-2.0, bold

I want to add style to this code:

```
<?php echo h($product['Product']['name']); ?>
```

I try to put this way:

```
<?php echo h($product['Product']['name'], array('style' => 'font-weight:bold;')); ?>
```

But it give me this error message:

Warning (2): htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 4 to be boolean, array given [CORE\Cake\basics.php, line 199]

can someone tell me the right way to add style to that line.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h() function is Convenience wrapper for htmlspecialchars() in cakephp. It Convert special characters to HTML entities. So you are getting the warning.

Syntax for this function is
h(string $text, boolean $double = true, string $charset = null)

To style your code you can use this alternatively

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->tag('span', $product['Product']['name'], array('style' => 'font-weight:bold;'));
?>
// Output
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Your Product Name</span>
```

Comment: It does not escape/xss-protect, though, this way!

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is:

```
<b><?php echo h($product['Product']['name']); ?></b>
```